# Jsoup Clean Whitelist issue

Tags: jsoup

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I am trying to do a basic clean of html file but for some reason my relative links change to rel="nofollow" when I use basic and I used the relax and set the preserveRelativeLinks to true and this removes the href....

here is my code:

```
File internalFile = new File(url);
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(internalFile, "UTF-8");             

    /** Get safe HTML from HTML, by parsing HTML and filtering it through a white-list of permitted tags and attributes. */
    document = new Cleaner(Whitelist.relaxed()
            .addTags("div", "em", "h1", "h2", "a")
            .addAttributes("div","class", "style", "name", "a", "href")
            .addProtocols("a", "href", "http", "https", "mailto")
            .preserveRelativeLinks(true)
            //resolvesRelativeLinks
            )
    .clean(document);   

    /** Select privactText tags from the id */
    Element divContent = document.select(eleId).first(); 

    /** Get all links inside div tag */
    Elements links = divContent.select("a[href]");      
    String exitUrl = "/exit?logout=true&amp;uri="; 

    /** Loop through links and add the exit.do to the link */

    for (Element link : links) {            
        link.attr("href", exitUrl + link.attr("href"));         
    }   

    /** Returned the text inside the div tag */     
    String parsedExternalContent =  divContent.html();
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When I try your code with `Whitelist.relaxed()`, it does not set the relative links to `rel="nofollow"` nor remove the `href`..

Comment: After
<li><a>Transparency</a></li>

here is all my code...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I fixed it... I just removed the clean up code and added after I select content from the div tag... not sure why but its working lol... Thanks again for your reply.